# How can i get rid of the max an min validation with having error in laravel 4.*?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-validation

I am having a problem with validation - the validation doesn't pass and it also doesn't show what type of error is making it

```
$rules = array(
        'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'company_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'zip_code' => 'required|integer|between:3,10',
        'address_1' => 'required|min:3',
        'address_2' => 'required|min:3',
        'city' => 'required|min:3',
        'country' => 'required|min:3',
        'state' => 'required|min:3',
        'phone_num' => 'required|integer|between:4,10',
        'security_answer' => 'required|min:10',
        'password' => 'required|min:3|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required'
    );
```

This is how I am retrieving errors

```
{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}
{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}
```

and so on

if I remove `|between:4,10` from the `phone_num` and `zip_code`everything works fine otherwise it doesn't show me any error but also doesn't pass the validation

Is there something wrong I am doing here? I tried finding the answer online but couldn't understand the problem here

Answer (score 0):

You should change validation rules

```
 'zip_code' => 'required|integer|between:3,10'
 'phone_num' => 'required|integer|between:4,10'
```

to

```
   'zip_code' => 'required|digits|between:3,10'
   'phone_num' => 'required|digits|between:4,10'
```

Your validation rule now for zip code expects an integer between 3 to 10. I suppose you need numeric value with length from 3 to 10.